# I want to insert data into db table using sequelize and iam using lambda function to insert data

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

Already I have existing db along with table created, I want to insert data to postgres db using sequelize. What procedure I need to follow.

Comment: You need to show a bit of an attempt, StackOverflow is for assistance not entire solutions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an overview of the services that you need to setup. I've done this twice and this diagram is from the first time I did it. The only thing you don't need is the bastion and its connection, so you can just ignore that part:

[image: architectural diagram]

These are the components:

- **VPC**: This is Virtual Private Cloud a virtual network that is separated from the rest of AWS. Inside the VPC:

  - **Public S.N.**: This is a subnet to which an Internet Gateway (IGW) is attached. It allows access to traffic outside of the VPC, such as the internet at large.
  - **Private S.N.**: This is a subnet that isn't accessible to anything outside of itself unless configure to using a Network Address Translation (NAT) Gateway.
- **Route Table**: This is a list of rules as to where traffic can go. The routing rules from the Private S.N. (the purple arrows from the Lambda and RDS) to the NAT Gateway is what allows traffic to pass from the Private S.N. to the Public S.N. The Route Table determines whether a subnet is private or public depending on the rules in the Route Table.
- **IGW**: The Internet Gateway is added to the VPC and connected to the Public S.N. using the NAT Gateway
- **RDS**: This will be your existing postgres db instance.
- **Lambda**: This will contain your Sequelize instance, code to connect to the RDS, get records, etc. The Lambda and the RDS must be in the same subnet. There may be multiple subnets associated with the RDS, the Lambda doesn't have to be in all of them, but it has to be in at least one of them.
- **APIG**: The API Gateway that is connected to your Lambda so it can be called. I'm not sure how you want to call your lambda but this is a pretty standard way if you want an API endpoint to call.

That's an overview of what's involved. Here are some resources that I used to help me set it up the first time I did it:

- https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7
- https://shontauro.medium.com/how-can-i-turn-my-restful-api-into-a-serverless-application-and-deploy-it-to-aws-lambda-step-by-8ff6cc97780f